# Passing json encode data from controller to view using ajax in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

I select data from controller and I want to display it on view. I want to display it in bootstrap view. Where should I put this to load view inmybootstrap template:

```
$data['sidebar']='member/dokter/sidebar_psn';
$data['content']='member/dokter/odontogram';
$this->load->view('member/dokter/main',$data);
```

My controller :

```
$data['odontogram']=$this->m_pasien->DtOdontogram($id_pasien);
            echo json_encode($data);
```

Result :

{"odontogram":[
{"gigi":"P53","posisi":"C","kondisi":"amf"},{"gigi":"P61","posisi":"C","kondisi":"amf"},{"gigi":"P21","posisi":"C","kondisi":"amf"}]}

I put ajax function in my view. Can I make the table in view?

```
function load(){
          $.ajax({
              url:"<?php echo base_url('c_dokter/odontogram');?>",
              type:"GET",
              data:{
                'id_odontogram': id_odontogram,
                "id_pasien": id_pasien,
                "gigi": gigi,
                "posisi": posisi,
                "kondisi": kondisi,
              },
              dataType:'json',
              success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
              },
              error:function(){
                alert('error ... ');
              }

            });


        }
```

Comment: Is console.log(data); receives results?

Answer (score 0):

```
function load(){
      $.ajax({
          url:"<?php echo base_url('c_dokter/odontogram');?>",
          type:"GET",
          data:{
            'id_odontogram': id_odontogram,
            "id_pasien": id_pasien,
            "gigi": gigi,
            "posisi": posisi,
            "kondisi": kondisi,
          },
          dataType:'json',
          success:function(){
            var parseData = JSON.parse(data);
            //foreach then append tr and td 
          },
          error:function(){
            alert('error ... ');
          }

        });


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first decode the json data and use foreach like these..

```
$arr = json_decode('[{"gigi":"P53","posisi":"C","kondisi":"amf"},{"gigi":"P61","posisi":"C","kondisi":"amf"},{"gigi":"P21","posisi":"C","kondisi":"amf"}]');

foreach($arr as $item) { 
    $uses = $item['gigi']; 
}
```